# Assigning Contacts to Partner Community user

Tags: field-update, partner-communities

I have a Partner Community set up with Partner users created.
I want to assign a contact to a partner user using a workflow but I can see this user in the field update wizard. I only see internal users.
How can I achieve this automation?

Comment: Does the Partner User own the Account the Contacts are related to?

Comment: @crmprogdev these contacts have no account

Comment: Unless the user is associated with an Account, I don't know how you'd be able to assign them to the Partner User. Ownership is pretty much always through some relationship with account. Is the contact actually more of a Lead perhaps? Your partner user may need to create some kind of "dummy account" to hold the contacts they create which they're not going to associate with an account of their own.